# Android - How can I determine an appropriate height for my ListView items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am building an Android app with a `ListView`. Coming from iOS I am used to setting fixed pixel  heights for list view items, since the screen sizes of the used devices are always the same. Now for Android, I am wondering what is a good way to dynamically set the heights of `ListView` items so that it it looks nice on all screen sizes?

Comment: Use **wrap_content** (so it automatically fits the content's height) or, if you want to use a fixed value, try **48dp** (**dp**, not px). It's a good value, most of the times, then tweak it to fit your needs

Comment: So, is it common to set fixed heights on Android as well? With **wrap_content** I'd have the issue that I am displaying icons on the items as well, which I am creating as bitmaps of a specific size (not the original sizes because then I'd run into memory issues). So, using **wrap_content**, could I programmatically access the items' height and create the bitmaps accordingly?

Comment: Can you give an example? Because if you use wrap_content on the layout of the list items, they will be the same size. But if you use different image heights or allow multiple lines for a TextView, there is no default concept.

Comment: By using a fixed height, you will make sure that all items in your ListView are even. If you use wrap_content you will ensure that all your rows will show their whole content. You could programmatically resize all your images at a fixed size and use wrap_content, for a higher flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android there are two famous properties. They are:

1. MATCH_PARENT formerly FILL_PARENT using this property for layout width or height will expand the view to the parents width or height minus margins
2. WRAP_CONTENT using this property for layout width or height will allow the view to take as much space required or available(if it exceeds screen dimension exception is inside scrollable views)

So for your  tag set both width and height to match_parent. And in the custom row that you might be populating set the root layout width to match_parent and height to wrap_content.

Note: in android while we give fixed height at times but it is generally not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But when using `MATCH_PARENT`, what is the parent of the list view item? I define the list view item in a `LinearLayout`, wouldn't the parent of the list view item be the `ListView` itself? And for `WRAP_CONTENT` my concern is that I am using Bitmaps that I load into memory in a specific size, so in that case I'd have to set a fixed size to the Bitmaps and can not load them dynamically according to the list view items' height?!

Comment: `will expand the view to the parents width or height` Not exactly: will expand the view to the remaining parents **available** width or height

Comment: parent of the listview item would be listivew and the parent of listview is linearlayout. As for the bitmaps, try using universal image loader from the very beginning as it will save you a lot of bitmap releated headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that really helps! As for the universal image loader, if only I had gotten this hint earlier!! I actually already implemented all the Bitmap logic, and yes, a lot of headache involved!! Thanks for the hint again!

Comment: note that is UIL you can specify the bitmap size directly cache in disk or memory load rgb_565(consumes 1/2 memory) and lot of other features. read and try the samples first then only delve into code.

Comment: `rgb_565(consumes 1/2 memory)` ... in sacrifice of **quality**.

Comment: @DerGolem I know that I used rgb_565 and argb_8888 and frankly my eye were unable to detect any change. Its like a paradox trying to figure how galaxy s5 display is better than s4 visually you hardly find any change

Comment: I can notice a difference like between **day and night**.

Comment: One more question guys, I still need to specify a size when creating the `Bitmap` for the icon. How can I chose the size appropriately? Can I programmatically get information what the items height is when I am using `MATCH_PARENT`?